# How to mod a string when out of bounds?

Tags: java, string, char

What this does is you get to choose the letters you want to pick from the String Choice and then they get converted by the number chosen in the integer converter. How do I do it so that when it reaches out of bounds it can go back to the first value, which in this case is "F"?

```
String Letters = "FEDCBA9876543210";

int converter;
Scanner lire = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("hint: FEDCBA9876543210\n");
System.out.print("message?: ");
message = lire.nextLine();

System.out.print("Delta no?: ");
converter = lire.nextInt();
char test[] = message.toCharArray();
int check;
System.out.print("resultat: ");
//Convertisseur ROT
for (int i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
    test[i] = Choice.charAt(i+ converter);
    check = i+ converter;

    System.out.print(test[i]);
}
```

Comment: You're not saying what Choice is. Also, it's not very clear what should happen (what is the input? What is the expected output?). You may probably want to rephrase a bit your question.

Comment: Do you want to perform a kind of ROT? Does `message` contain only letters a-z? Please show sample message and expected result.

Comment: @Bohemian basically yes and only with the letters inside the String choice.

Comment: @MatteoNNZ If I were to choose the letter F from the string choice and have the converter of 2, it would convert it to the letter D.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I don't understand the whole question but maybe this can help you:
instead of `Choice.charAt(i+ converter)` you can try to use the remainder of the division by the length of the array, that is `Choice.charAt((i+converter)%Choice.lenght)`; so when the index goes out of bounds it return to the first element.